# Resolve the InsecureRequestWarning without disabling it

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, python-requests, proxy

I'm trying to execute a network request within Python 3, using the requests module, to get data from a remote REST server.

The request goes through a proxy that requires an SSL certificate, which I have.
This SSL certificate is created from a key that I made and signed by the proxy administrator, they also gave me a PEM certificate bundle as the proxy key is self-certified.

I specify the request like so:

```
import requests

url='http://rest.lab/'

proxies = {
    'http': 'https://proxy.lab/',
    'https': 'https://proxy.lab/'
}

resp= requests.get(url, timeout=30, proxies=proxies, cert=('./local.cert', './local.key'), verify='./ca.pem')
```

While the connection works and returns the expected data, I cannot get rid of the InsecureRequestWarning warning.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1045: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'proxy.lab'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
```

I followed the provided URL but it talks about using Mozilla's root cert bundle, which is not going to help here since the proxy server does not use any external CAs.

Searching the internet returns many pages that provide instructions on how to disable or hide this warning, but that seems totally wrong to me. It's a warning, it needs to be fixed not hidden away.

Sadly I cannot find any way of getting the requests module to use the CA provided.

I looked in to using the auth= option but that seems to be just for authentication at the end point, not at the proxy.

Can anyone provide suggestions or pointers on how to resolve this without just hiding it?

(Edited to put the correct protocol in the URL being queried)

Comment: `ca.pem` must include the (private) CA certificate for your proxy and the (public) CA certificate for the site you are trying to reach, since both the certificate from the proxy and also the certificate from the target site need to be validated.

Comment: Thanks @Steffen-Ullrich. The site I am trying to reach is an HTTP one (it's internal). Oh, I see I got that wrong in the example, a mistake on my part. I'll fix my question.

Comment: If there is really only a HTTP request over a HTTPS proxy then ca.pem must include the CA of the proxy. Note that if the proxy is using a self-signed certificate it has to be actually a CA certificate, i.e. basic constraints CA:true. Otherwise it gets ignored. Also, it might be that your internal HTTP sites is actually redirecting to HTTPS in which case you would also need the respective CA in ca.pem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Steffen-Ullrich for the assistance and information.

I have resolved my problem although, sadly, it's not going to help anyone else.

It turns out the proxy that I am using is not actually proxying in the same sense as standard HTTP[S] proxies. Instead the end result is appended to the 'proxy' URL and it sorts out the redirect. So:

```
https://proxy.lab/site/dest.lab/
```

will do what is needed. I still have a problem with this but it is a different question so I won't muddy this one.